# How to force Y axis to use integers in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is the graph I get, when I have only numbers below 2. I am generating a report and I'd like to use only integers on Y axis labels. Is there a way to force it in PHPExcel? All the numbers are integers, since they are ratings ranging 1-5. Bars represent the number of ratings.
[image: Graph]

The options to change are major/minor units in Excel:

[image: Excel options]